# Compound expressions mixing generic methods and Java 8 syntax do not compile

Tags: java, generics, java-8

Using Java 8 update 20, the below class does not compile, it fails with an error of "incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s)". Using Eclipse 4.4.0, this does however compile and run using the JDT compiler. To make it compile with the standard Java compiler, the transformation `letters.stream().map(l -> l + "1").collect(Collectors.toList())` must be carried out separately. Does anyone know if this is a bug in the Java compiler or part of the specification? If this behaviour is as intended, why do the JDT and standard compilers differ?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CompileTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> letters = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
        int pos = Collections.binarySearch(letters.stream().map(l -> l + "1").collect(Collectors.toList()), "C1", (l1, l2) -> l1.compareTo(l2));
        System.out.println(pos);
    }

}
```

Comment: As a side comment you could use `String::compareTo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran into a bug in the current `jdk1.8.0_20`. Using the beta of `jdk1.8.0_40` it compiles without errors.

You can use a work-around for `jdk1.8.0_20`:

```
List<String> letters = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
int pos = Collections.<String>binarySearch(
    letters.stream().map(l -> l + "1").collect(Collectors.toList()),
    "C1", (l1, l2) -> l1.compareTo(l2));
System.out.println(pos);
```

or you replace the lambda expression for the `Comparator` with a method reference. This gives a hint to the compiler about the type on which `compareTo` shall be invoked:

```
List<String> letters = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
int pos = Collections.binarySearch(
    letters.stream().map(l -> l + "1").collect(Collectors.toList()),
    "C1", String::compareTo);
System.out.println(pos);
```

---

But you can also simplify your code. Since `String` already implements `Comparable`, you don’t need to specify a lambda expression for the `Comparator`:

```
List<String> letters = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
int pos = Collections.binarySearch(
    letters.stream().map(l -> l + "1").collect(Collectors.toList()), "C1");
System.out.println(pos);
```

This simplification has the side-effect of reducing the complexity of the type inference and can be compiled with `jdk1.8.0_20` without problems.

Comment: My example is not perfect since, as you point out, String is Comparable but I opted for strings here anyway for simplicity. My question regards general objects. I look forward to update 40, then!

Comment: I’m also waiting patiently for a stable, mostly bug free, compiler (and hope that u40 will be that one)…